# Giving a <option> tag a class? API call is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, html-select

I'm practicing API calls using AJAX and JavaScript/jQuery. I am currently using the Random User API (https://randomuser.me/). For some reason, the AJAX call doesn't execute correctly when I try to call users by nationality. I'm wondering if it's because I am giving the  tags classes of "nationality"? At first, I gave the  tag this class, but I figured that wasn't quite right. Where am I going wrong here? Every user I try to call is Australian because that nationality just happens to be first on the list. Can anyone give me some tips on how to call the API correctly?

Here's my HTML:

```
<h1> Random Person Generator </h1>
    <div class = "info">
        <p> Generate a Random Person! </p>
            <form class = "zipform">
            <p> Nationality? </p>
                <select name = "nationality">
                    <option value = "au" class ="nationality">Australian</option>
                    <option value = "br" class ="nationality">Brazilian</option>
                    <option value = "ca" class ="nationality">Canadian</option>
                    <option value = "ch" class ="nationality">Swiss</option>
                    <option value = "de" class ="nationality">German </option>
                    <option value = "dk" class ="nationality">Norweigan </option>
                    <option value = "es" class ="nationality"> Spanish </option>
                    <option value = "fi" class ="nationality">Finnish</option>
                    <option value = "fr" class ="nationality">French</option>
                    <option value = "gb" class ="nationality">British </option>
                    <option value = "us" class ="nationality">American </option>
                    <option value = "nl" class ="nationality">Dutch </option>
                    <option value = "nz" class ="nationality">New Zealander </option>
                    <option value = "tr" class ="nationality">Turkey</option>
                    </select>
                <button type = "submit" class = "pure_button"> Search </button>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </form>
            <div class = "rando_facts">
                <p id = "intro"> </p>
                <p id = "name"> </p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

And my JS/jQuery:

```
$('.pure_button').click(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault()
    console.log("click noticed")

$.ajax({


    url: "http://api.randomuser.me" + "/?nat=" + $('.nationality').val(),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {

        console.log("This works too")
        debugger
        console.log(data)
        $('#intro').text("Presenting...")
        var firstName = data.results[0].name.first
        var lastName = data.results[0].name.last
        $('#name').text("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName)
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4s057mho/) - change country and click on search button to see result

To get your selected option, use this. If you just use the class and `.val()`, you will always get the first option.

`url: "http://api.randomuser.me" + "/?nat=" + $("[name=nationality]").find("option:selected" ).text(),`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I actually used .val() instead of .text() on the end, as I needed the exact value as opposed to the text. But that did fix the issue nicely.

Comment: @Leia_Organa - glad to help. Please accept this as answer if it helped :) Thank you!